# Creating a GeoServer user with admin rights to a single store / workspace

Tags: geoserver

Is it possible to create a GeoServer user with admin rights to manage a particular store or workspace? If so how? I've read the online documentation and played with the admin UI but can't work it out.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I haven’t actually tried anything as I’ve not found any instructions online. I’ve searched the admin UI and found no such feature, my question is whether or not the feature exists.

Comment: Did you miss https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/index.html ?